# Can beans be overcooked?

Tags: beans, legumes, overcooking

Can beans be overcooked? Coffee beans, for example, are incredibly roasted. Falafel is baked or fried garbanzo beans. Is it possible to overcook beans, or is this good for breaking down the sugars, phytic acid that cause flatulence, indigestion of legumes?

Comment: If reducing flatulence from beans is the desired effect, you should check [another question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/what-can-i-do-to-help-prevent-flatulence-from-beans) that deals with the topic. In general, you soak beans, don't overcook them, to minimize bloating. Additionally, consuming beans and other fiber rich foods regularly should reduce the discomfort caused by bloatedness.

Comment: I'd like to add that Coffee beans aren't actual beans.

Comment: @HAEM [AMTwo noted that below](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/120091/42013): "Coffee beans aren't really beans--they're seeds from a fruit".

Comment: What are "lentil beans"? Falafel is usually made from chickpeas or broad/fava beans.

Comment: @psmears Yes, garbanzos are usually used, but see: "[Cooking vs Soaking Lentils for Falafel](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/114333/42013)."

Comment: One **should be cautious** with overcooked (especially burnt-tasting) food. Acrylamide (AA) is found in significant concentration in crisp bread and fried potato and coffee. Rydberg et al. (2004) found that AA in fried potato reached 100−900 μg/kg, confirmed in restaurant-prepared food (≈500 μg/kg in french fries), and even 4 mg/kg in potato crisps. Microwave heating also generated AA. Uncooked potato and boiled potato had undetectable levels. AA in crisp bread can reach 1.7 mg/kg. The amount of AA in coffee is much lower, but the point is that it is an undesirable by-product of *roasting*.

Comment: Gokmen et al. (2006) showed that temperature drastically influenced the AA yield; frying a potato strip for 9 min yielded undectable AA at 150°C, but 400 μg/kg at 170°C, and 1.4 mg/kg at 190°C. Zhivagui et al. (2019) identified a human genome mutation signature of AA carcinogenicity that occurred in 1/3 of tumour genomes, including lung cancers (88%) and liver (73%) and kidney (>70%). Many tumors with this signature had other genetic markers that strongly suggest that their mutations were due to dietary/occupational exposures to AA unrelated to tobacco smoking (which is the biggest AA source).

Comment: The point is that cooking things too long can generate undesirable substances. On the other hand, do note that some food *must* be cooked to destroy undesirable substances! For instance, raw cashew nuts have toxic levels of urushiol that is also found in poison ivy, and so they must be cooked/roasted.

Comment: Overcooked can mean three things - cooked too long, too hot, or both.  Which are you asking about?

Comment: @J... By "overcooked" I mean whatever decreases the nutritional quality the most.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Beans can absolutely be overcooked.

Coffee beans aren't really beans--they're seeds from a fruit--but they are very temperature sensitive when roasted. There is a wide range of roasts, but dark roast in particular is essentially brought right to the edge and stopped before burning. For folks who like lighter or medium roasts, even dark roasts of coffee can be unpalatably burnt tasting.

As far as legumes and "real" beans go--absolutely. Beans can still be burnt (such as over-fried falafel, or grilled haricots verts), or overcooked until they just turn to mush. If you simmer bean soup long enough, the beans will just disintegrate and lose their shape.

Dried beans in particular **are** fairly forgiving--there's a pretty wide range where they are edible & enjoyable. The long cook time on dried beans means hitting the doneness between "not crunchy" and "not mushy" is fairly easy.

Fresh beans (haricots verts, green chick peas, fava beans, etc) are quite the opposite. Like other fresh vegetables, the cook time is relatively short and thus it is easy to turn them into a mash by overcooking for just a few minutes. Some people do like mushy vegetables--but many would consider mushy fresh vegetables (including fresh beans) to be a culinary sin.

Comment: What prompted my question was soaking dried pinto beans overnight, slow-cooking them all day, food-processing them, then baking / "crispifying" them at 400°F for 30 min. Surprisingly, the beans withstood all that, maintaining their flavor and nutritional quality.

Comment: There's no way to know the "nutritional quality" unless you analyzed a sample in a lab. To the point of the question you asked, plus the details in your comment here--if you had left the beans in the oven for longer, they certainly would have burned eventually, likely getting both an acrid taste and overly hard texture.

Comment: If you have a more specific question, I'd encourage you to ask another question with enough detail to convey the "problem" (or concern, etc) you're trying to solve . Overly generic questions can often lead to answers that don't address your real want, and be unsatisfying.

Comment: Just to add to the dried beans aspect - this very much depends on the type of bean and whether you have pre-soaked them. With soaked mung beans for example, I have to set my pressure cooker to 0 minutes because just the process of reaching temperature is enough to cook them and any more turns them to mush. Soaked kidney beans on the other hand require 25 mins otherwise they are unpleasantly crunchy. Cooking pinto beans all day and then baking for 30 mins sounds excessive to me - I do mine for around 35 mins in the pressure cooker for refried beans (albeit pressure cooking is faster).

Comment: @Geremia: By processing and baking/crispifying them; you are circumventing the main issue with overcooking, i.e. the mushy beans AMtwo focuses on. I would argue that in doing so, you've _repurposed_ your beans from the initial cooking (or potential overcooking), to the point where the consideration of having overcooked them is no longer all that relevant, and the pertinent question would be more akin to "can you repurpose overcooked beans?"

Comment: Green beans especially: 0.001 milliseconds between "tough and stringy" and "mush" :)

Comment: "_Coffee beans aren't really beans--they're seeds from a fruit_" Beans are seeds, too, no?

Comment: Beans are seeds, but not all seeds are beans. Beans usually refer to the seeds from certain legumes. Nuts are also seeds--but not from legumes.  And of course there are peanuts, which are legumes, but considered nuts rather than beans. Like with much edible classifications, it's quite fuzzy.  When people generally refer to "beans" they mean "a seed from a pod" where coffee beans are not that--**botanically speaking** coffee beans are closer to a brazil nut or white rice than to a pinto bean.

Answer (score 5):

I found this detailed article on the topic of [Can You Overcook Beans? (Things to Know)](https://homecookworld.com/can-you-overcook-beans/), below is a quote from it *(I've also added additional highlighting to the important parts)*:

> #### Conclusion
>
> **Can you overcook beans?**
>
> Well, the answer to this question is that it depends. Overcooked beans will have an **undesirable texture**, but they **may not be harmful if eaten**. Furthermore, most people will spit them out rather than swallow them and ingest overcooked food.
>
> So, [overcooking] certainly can take away from the flavor and make beans taste bad. But, if you overcook your beans, don’t worry! **Just add some seasoning** (especially salt) to help mask that off-putting texture.

Comment: It's bad advice to say that you should add seasoning to cover up bad taste, because in general bad taste is a strong indicator of unhealthy or even toxic contents.